# Get all the Tile layers added to the map using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers, tiles

I want to get all the Tile layers which are added in the base_map. When I am using  `map.getLayers()` I get the list in the `array_`.  How can I identify all the charts and remove the individual charts.

My process to add the code is:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.TileWMS({ 
     url:url,
     serverType: 'geoserver'
    }) 
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Any suggestions will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the layers array to return only layers whose source has a getTileGrid method (which would include VectorTile layers)

```
var tileLayers = map.getlayers().getArray().filter(function(layer){
  return layer.getSource() && layer.getSource().getTileGrid
});
```

or you could use `instanceOf`

```
var tileLayers = map.getlayers().getArray().filter(function(layer){
  return layer instanceOf ol.layer.Tile
});
```

If you have layer groups you would also need to search those